# Parsing a text file into strings (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, file, list, text

I am trying to write a coded that reads in a text file into an array list. However, I am unsure how to parse my text file into strings to correctly be put into an array list. Here is a sample text file that I need to use.

This should be the sample question.

```
2
one
two
three
four
0
4
6
```

My Java code below:

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class JavaApplication8 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner inScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String file_name;
    System.out.print("What is the full file path name?\n>>");
    file_name = inScan.next();

    Scanner fScan = new Scanner(new File(file_name));
    int numItems = Integer.parseInt(fScan.nextLine());
    ArrayList<String> Questions = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        Questions.add(fScan.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.print("The array is: " + Questions);



}
```

Comment: Does the file contain blank spaces between each value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment about the variable `numLines` below, you don't need to parse integers from the content so you can remove the line:

```
int numItems = Integer.parseInt(fScan.nextLine());
```

Then to output every line to the array, you can use `Scanner.hasNextLine()`:

```
while (fScan.hasNextLine()) {
   questions.add(fScan.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: What is the significance of `numItems`? Why not do an open-ended read? What is your _expected_ output?

Comment: I do not know why I am not getting the same output. My output is an error code:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "This should be the question"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at javaapplication8.JavaApplication8.main(JavaApplication8.java:23)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I do not know why, but my code just gave me the desired output. Thanks so much

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(...)` expects `String`s, in the format of `int`s, if not,a `NumberFormatException` is thrown