# Sorting a text file's info in Java using line.contains

Tags: java, indexof

I am writing a program that asks the user a quiz. I must read in a text file with the info I need. However, I've run into trouble as to how to do this. I have sorted as many questions I need into a list array, but the rest is giving me trouble. Here is the format of the text files I must use:

(Question)
(Number of answer out of the choices)
(x number of choices)
(number tried)
(number correct)
(number incorrect)

How would I go about using the code I have to distinguish between the answer integers and the statistic integers?

```
    Scanner fScan = new Scanner(new File(file_name));


    List<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> other = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[] answers = new int[questions.size()];



    while (fScan.hasNextLine()) 
    {

        String line = fScan.nextLine();

    if (line.contains("?")) 
    {
        questions.add(line);

    } 
    else 
    {
        other.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your input file look like? are (Question) (Number of answer out of the choices) (x number of choices) (number tried) (number correct) (number incorrect) in same line or different line

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187130/parsing-a-text-file-into-strings-java "Same OP") I understand that they are on separate lines.

Comment: and can you keep statistic integers and answer integers in different files? the best way would be to use a database

Comment: They are on different lines, sorry for the lack of clarification

Comment: Just a side note, with the following you are just creating a zero-sized array - int[] answers = new int[questions.size()];

Comment: Can you add an example that represents a line in your input file? The format you have presented is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a `Map` with questions as the key and List of answers as value e.g. below:

```
Map<String, List<String>> questionAnswersMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> answers = null;
while (fScan.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = fScan.nextLine();
   if (line.contains("?")){
      //new Question
      answers = new ArrayList<String>()
      questionAnswersMap.put(line, answers );
   }else{
      //answer of the previous question
      answers.add(line);
   } 
}
```

Here I am assuming that questions and answers are written in the sequence.